# Simulators don't start (Xcode 10 GM)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode10

I've updated to Xcode 10 GM, removed the Xcode 10 beta but for some reason none of the simulators ever start. After waiting for awhile, I get this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (DVTCoreSimulatorAdditionsErrorDomain error 0.)

[image: Screenshot]

What does that mean and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently the only solution is to restart your Mac

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions for this:

1. Quit simulator (shortcut: cmd + Q) and try again
2. Reset simulator content. Select `Simulator`. Goto `Hardware` tab -> `Erase All Content and Settings...`

[image: screenshot]

OR

Run `xcrun simctl erase all`  command in terminal.

3. Restart you Mac machine

Solution 2 worked for me!